# Stop synchronising the call history log between iPhones on shared Apple ID?

Tags: call, history

How to stop synchronising the call history log between my two iPhones that share the same Apple ID. I know this is related to the Apple ID but I have no choice since I have to use my shared iCloud contact list by both iPhones.

Is there a workaround to avoid duplicate calls registering in both iPhones? For example, when I receive a missed call in one iPhone it shows up in the second iPhone as a missed call in the call history log.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2613?locale=en_US

Comment: @TheBro21 Could you elaborate? The linked support article doesn't mention call history.

Comment: iOS 9.2.1 appears to have fixed this... are you still experiencing this issue after updating all your devices to 9.2.1?

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off iCloud drive on all iPhones. You can optionally keep it on in one of the iPhones, but make sure it's turned of on all others sharing the apple ID. This worked for me.

Comment: On  iOS 10.3.2, my answer no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that toggling airplane mode on the 2nd phone fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Could you elaborate on your answer? Please give context, steps and results to help other users to better interpret your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My pervious answer was wrong. Call history is shared between iOS devices via iCloud Drive. http://www.imore.com/apple-comments-icloud-call-history-sync-what-you-need-know